# SQL search inside a link_to in Rails is it possible and how or alternatives?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Hi everybody I'm new with rails and I'm having problems doing link_to passing id, everything i need etc; I dont understand Rails that much so since i have a deadline for my work I wonder if i can just make a sql search within the link to. Yes I know it's not the way to do it but my grade depends on it.

Comment: This information is not enough to solve your problem please elaborate in more details and example.

Comment: Im doing a tennis store and im trying to show raquets or shoes or whatever by their brand  and I want to know if inside the link to I can make the search for the specific items to be presented and if not what is the correct approach to do what i'm rying to do

Answer (score 1):

Your "link" won't be able to handle an SQL query directly, you'll have to send data to your server one way or another

---

**HTTP**
You can send an HTTP request to the server pretty simply like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "search(/:term)", to: "#controller#serach"

#app/views/controller/view.html.erb
<%= link_to "Search", search_path("query") %>

#app/controllers/controller_controller.rb
def search
    @search = Model.where("name LIKE ?", params[:query])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end
end
```

Obviously this is VERY simplistic, but hopefully shows you that the search functionality is literally just an SQL call on the server. The difference is how you request it

---

**Ajax**

If you wanted "live" functionality, you could send the request through [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). This uses Javascript to send an *asynchronous" request to your server, allowing you to send the query without having to reload the page

You can do this like this:

```
#view
<%= link_to "Search", search_path("query"), remote: :true %>

#app/views/controller/search.js.erb
//do something to append data to your view
```

Comment: No problem - if it helped, you may consider upvoting :)